# Overview image not available for public users (updated)

Tags: geonetwork, tomcat, configuration

**Update2: I tracked down the issue down (pressing F12 and reloading the page) to how requests for images are being handled. The catalog resources that display externally request those resources using 18.237.120.61:8080 for the Domain. The images that are not displaying are using the localhost:8080 domain for the request. So, something somewhere is not configured correctly.

That said, I do not know if I need to change the configuration in Tomcat or GeoNetwork. Any ideas on what to update?**

Environment:
AWS EC2,
Ubuntu 22.04 w/ Gnome desktop,
GeoNetwork 4.2.3 (WAR install)
Tomcat 9.0.76

Issue:
I am in the process of setting up a GeoNetwork catalog and have run into a weird issue. I cannot view overview images, the spatial extent image, or provider logo when accessing the catalog from an external computer. This is the same whether I am logged onto the catalog as an administrator or accessing as a public user.

Currently, I have not customized the application other than to load templates and sample metadata to test the app.

The overview, spatial extent, and logo images display properly, when viewing the catalog on the EC2 instance itself, regardless of whether I am logged into the catalog as an administrator or viewing as a public user.

**Update1: Accessed the catalog as a public, non-privileged user on an external computer, and while the issue regarding the overview and spatial extent images is still the same, I tried a couple exports of the metadata, one a PDF the other as a ZIP file, from the individual record page and the overview image, spatial extent, and provider logo were included with each export. This means GeoNetwork can access those images and use them when viewing externally, but does not display them when viewing the records in the catalog.

What I have done so far:

1. The sample records in the catalog were published by GeoNetwork when they were added along with their templates.
2. Tested viewing records from an external computer using Firefox, Google Chrome, and Edge browsers and the issue is the same for all of them.
3. Ran the 'Delete and create data index' and 'Delete index and reindex' Admin tools a couple times.
4. Have shutdown and restarted Tomcat.

I have looked through the GeoNetwork settings and nothing has jumped out at me. Any ideas what might be going on, or file configs I may have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been quite awhile, but I ran into this again when the IP address of the AWS server hosting the catalog "spontaneously" changed (turned out my boss was messing with my server and screwed it up).

While one of the original issues was definitely that the IP address was incorrect in the GeoNetwork settings, it turns out the main issue was how images are referenced by the catalog. I had assumed the images had relative paths that referenced the IP address in the settings. However, all the image links in the metadata records are absolute. So, if the catalog is moved or something happens to the server IP address, the catalog is still looking for the metadata record images using the old IP address, while the records themselves can still be viewed because their location information is configured differently.

All that said, the fix is incredibly easy. For this latest issue, all I did was a search and replace on all the records to change the old IP address to the new one. After the catalog completed the  IP address switch on the image links of the existing records, all the images displayed when viewing the records.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I misunderstood how to configure GeoNetwork. Given the instructions for the various components were all based on localhost/127.0.0.1, I had, wrongly, assumed I should enter localhost as Host in Admin console > Settings > Catalog server.

At first, when I entered the server's public IP address for host nothing changed. It was the same after I deleted and recreated the index. The images still did not display when the catalog was viewed on a remote computer.

After rereading the description associated with that setting, I noticed the host address was used to create links during record editing so I decided to delete the existing records. After that I added the sample records back using Admin console > Metadata & templates. Since the public IP address was in the settings when recreating the sample records, all images now display at all levels of the catalog.

To confirm what I did applied to regular catalog records, I uploaded a test metadata file and attached an image to it in the editor. The result confirmed that the change applied to all new records.